# Way To Inject Javascript in PWA on Non-PWA Pages?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

If I make a Progressive Web App (PWA), and I change the display in the manifest.json file to `browser` instead of the typical `standalone` preference people usually choose for PWAs, and the user opens the app and surfs to some third-party site outside my control, such as Reddit.com, does this app still have control such as the ability to add Javascript and CSS into the page kind of like a Chrome Extension would?

Comment: Generally no. The whole point behind web security is to prevent things like this. The ability to inject javascript into reddit.com is called XSS and is usually considered a bug for reddit.com. Extensions are allowed to do this because presumably the browser user would be aware of it since they install the extension themselves (not always a valid assumption but better than being surprised that something like tinder.com (yes, there's a PWA version of Tinder) can insert random javascript into reddit.com or your gmail)

Comment: What about the fact that a worker script is running? Does Chrome give the PWA special functionality through that?

Comment: No. A web worker works the same in normal web pages and PWA. Web workers can only be started  by the page that wants to start a web worker. You cannot connect a web worker to another page (how would that work anyway? web workers don't have access to DOM and can only communicate back to your main script via messages and if the page you want to inject it to does not have any code to communicate with the web worker the web worker cannot really do anything useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: "browser"` does not give you a stand-alone application. It opens in a normal browser tab/window

I'm not sure of any browser that will actually let that be installable, either.

That doesn't pass installability criteria for Chrome, for instance

As for being able to inject CSS and JS into other pages, no, you can't do that, with any display mode. It's just a website in a fancy display. PWAs aren't web views like in mobile apps, and the browser still owns the overall display context (rendering, extensions, etc…), not the installed app